# xmlHTTPrequest status code 400

Tags: javascript, c#, xmlhttprequest

i want to get a response from my webserver. So i send a GET command to my api path "auftraege", but at xhht.send is an error "status code 400". The server has a controller to listen at "auftraege" and responses only "hello".

```
var xmlDoc = null;

function loadXML() {
var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 400) {
        updateXML(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "auftraege", true);
xhttp.send('grant_type=client_credentials');
}

function updateXML(xml) {
xmlDoc = xml.responseText;
document.getElementById("auftraege").innerHTML = xmlDoc;
setTimeout(updateTime, 5000);
}
window.addEventListener("load", loadXML);
```

---

That is the controller:

```
[RestController(InstanceCreationType.Singleton)] 
public class AuftraegeController { 
  [UriFormat("/auftraege")] 
  public IGetResponse GetWithSimpleParameters() { 
    return new GetResponse( GetResponse.ResponseStatus.OK, "Hello");
  }
```

---

That is the webserver

```
    private HttpServer _httpServer;

    public async Task InitializeWebServer()
    {
        var restRouteHandler = new RestRouteHandler();
        restRouteHandler.RegisterController<AuftraegeController>();

        var configuration = new HttpServerConfiguration()
            .ListenOnPort(80)
            //.RegisterRoute("api", restRouteHandler)
            .RegisterRoute("/auftraege", restRouteHandler)
            .RegisterRoute(new StaticFileRouteHandler(@"Web"))
            .EnableCors();

        var httpServer = new HttpServer(configuration);
        _httpServer = httpServer;
        await httpServer.StartServerAsync();
```

Comment: i'm using the package restup for windows iot

Comment: You should add tags for the serverside language/technology you are using.

Comment: what tags do you mean? serverside is c#

Comment: nobody has an idea? i edit the code of the webserver. And i used this package: https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup

Comment: restup seem quite obscure, try without params in .send() as the c# code is not decorated with anything that mentions them.  (this.status === 200 is used to detect success).  Try it from a browser & see if the same happens.

Comment: i tried it with the same result. oh yes === 200 of course

Comment: i used restup, cause i didn't find another solution to host my webinterface on windows iot. The last problem is only to get my xml data to this webinterface, cause the xml file is in the localfolder